# Assigning to list and plotting don't work in loop

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, patchwork

Let's say I have the function following :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
subplots <- function(data) {
  lst <- list()
  # Assigning first and second variable to the list
  for (i in 1:2) {
    lst[[i]] <- ggplot() +
      aes(x = 1:length(data[, i]), y = data[, i]) +
      geom_line()
  }
  # Plotting variables stored in the list 
  wrap_plots(lst)
}
```

The main purpose of this code is to take data frame and plot side by side plot of the first and second variable. However If I run this code on same data :

```
sed.seed(42)
vec_1 <- rnorm(100)
vec_2 <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame(vec_1, vec_2)
subplots(df)
```

I obtain two times second variable graph, instead of first and second.
[image]

Do you know how this can be repaired ? Am I assigning to list wrongly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list assignment is good but your `ggplot()` call has improper syntax.

Try:

```
subplots <- function(data) {
  lst <- list()
  # Assigning first and second variable to the list
  for (i in 1:2) {
    lst[[i]] <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:length(data[, i]), y = data[, i]), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_line()
  }
  # Plotting variables stored in the list 
  wrap_plots(lst)
}
```